# Preg_match url to get id numbers

Tags: php

I tried preg_match and explode and everything but doesnt get good solution for getting id numbers in url.

URL-s

```
$a = strtolower('<iframe src="//LearningApps.org/watch?app=1250652" style="border:0px;width:100%;height:500px" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>');
$b = strtolower('http://LearningApps.org/view1250652'); 
$c = strtolower('LearningApps.org/view1250652');
$d = strtolower('LearningApps.org/watch?app=1250652');
$e = strtolower('LearningApps.org');
$f = strtolower('http://learningapps.org/339473');
```

And i tried:

```
$match = '/[0-9]{7}/';
preg_match($match, $end, $matches);
print_R($matches);
```

But id lenght can change, so that isnt good solution for me.

Comment: You can set a minimum length with `/[0-9]{4,}/` to find all digit sequences with 4 digits or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As developer of the named service learningapps.org I can provide you with our own PHP function to parse URLs to get the ID:

```
function getLearningAppID($url){
  parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $params );
  $ID = null;
  $GUID = "";
  if(isset($params["v"])) $GUID = $params["v"];
  if(isset($params["id"])) $GUID = $params["id"];
  if($GUID == ""){
    // try AppID
    if(preg_match("@learningapps.org/(?:view)?(\d+)@i",$url,$matches)){
      $ID = $matches[1];
    }else{
      if(isset($params["app"])) $ID = $params["app"];
    }
  }

  // now you have either a value in $ID (public app) or $GUID (private app)
  ...
}
```

You can also always contact us directly by mail, we are happy to hear about development projects based on learningapps.org :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will work accurately if the iframe style values are same across your entire code:

```
$c = strtolower('<iframe src="//LearningApps.org/watch?app=1250652" style="border:0px;width:100%;height:500px" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>');
$numbers = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', substr($c, 0, -100)), 10);
echo $numbers;
```

Comment: It will still have problems when used with `$a = strtolower('<iframe src="//LearningApps.org/watch?app=1250652" style="border:0px;width:100%;height:500px" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>');`

Comment: If characters after style="border:....... are consistent across your code, then you can try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get only the digits, you can use regex.

```
preg_match("/([0-9]{5,})/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

[Check the code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cuo)

Or (but case if you have a string with some other numbers the regex below will not work correctly)

```
preg_replace("/\D/", "", $input_lines);
```

[Check the code](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cun)